# What are the Bunkers & Badasses event class mods?

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault

To celebrate the release of *Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep*, Gearbox put out [a series of special SHiFT codes](https://web.archive.org/web/20160414072118/http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1060) which grant special class mods to the player.

Since class mods gained by SHiFT codes are tied to the level of the first character loaded after redeeming the code, I've been a bit apprehensive about when or if I want to claim the codes. It would really help me out if I could know exactly what the class mods do, and what the range of their bonuses are. Unfortunately, I've had a hard time finding even so much as their names in online searches.

Does anyone have a list of the names of these mods? Ideally, I'd also like to know their minimum and maximum stats. But the names alone should be enough to help search for the stats.

Comment: I've listed the class mod names and variations in [my answer here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/148741/4797). Since there are too many TTAODK class mod variations, I won't be able to list all their stat ranges. What specific class mod levels and class requirements are you interested in? I can edit that into the Gibbed's Save Editor and look up the stats.

Answer (score 2):

The class mods spawned by the SHiFT codes will spawn as a random variety (random prefix, rarity, skill bonuses, etc) TTAODK class mod at your level. Related discussion posts: [Reddit /r/Borderlands2](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands2/comments/1hyh4g/borderlands_2_bunkers_badasses_shift_loot_yall/cazioi4?context=7), [Gearbox Forums (1)](https://archive.fo/FaNG4) [(2)](https://archive.fo/GdsHL).

The possible varieties of the TTAODK class mods are:

| TTAODK class mod | Class requirement | Skill bonuses (depends on rarity) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Barbarian | Psycho / Krieg | Blood Trance, Fire Fiend, Salt the Wound |
| Cleric | Siren / Maya | Life Tap, Restoration, Suspension |
| Monk | Gunzerker / Salvador | Asbestos, Money Shot, Sexual Tyrannosaurus |
| Necromancer | Mechromancer / Gaige | Made of Sterner Stuff, Strength of Five Gorillas, Wires Don't Talk |
| Ranger | Commando / Axton | Impact, Ranger, Grit |
| Rogue | Assassin / Zero | Like The Wind, Tw0 Fang, Vel0city |

The rarity of a class mod determines how many skills it will affect and how many skill points are added:

| Rarity | Skill bonuses | Skill points added |
| --- | --- | --- |
| White | None | n/a |
| Green | 1 | +5 |
| Blue | 2 | +6, +5 |
| Purple | 3 | +5, +4, +4 |

The prefix on these class mods determines what player variables (e.g. Fire Rate, Magazine Size, etc) are affected. The class mods will grant two of the following bonuses up to the specified amount (at level 61; bonuses could go even higher if you have the [Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack Two](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Digistruct_Peak_Challenge) DLC which increases the level cap to 72)  depending on class mod level and the full name of the class mod:

- Accuracy: +31% ("Lawful" in the name)
- Critical Damage: +45% ("Evil" in the name)
- Fire Rate: +31% ("Chaotic" in the name)
- Magazine Size: +73% ("True Neutral" in the name) or +45% ("Neutral" in the name)
  Note: The "True Neutral" class mod grants two separate Magazine Size bonuses and thus will display them as a single bonus. All others will display two distinct bonuses.
- Reload Speed: +45% ("Good" in the name)

For example, a purple rarity (3 skill bonuses; +5, +4, +4 skill points), level 67, "Chaotic Evil" (fire rate and critical damage bonuses) Necromancer class mod could show up as:
[image: Chaotic Evil Necromancer class mod]

---

<sup>Class mod info are from: Borderlands Wiki articles, "[Class Mod](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Class_Mod_(Borderlands_2))" and the specific TTAODK class mod articles</sup>

Comment: Woah! Didn't know alignments give same bonuses across classes - very cool!

Comment: Good general information to have, but I'm specifically interested in the class mods granted by the SHiFT codes. Is it just a random quality/alignment choice from the mod for a given class? Or are they all of a specific quality and alignment?

Comment: @Iszi According to this [Reddit /r/Borderlands discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands2/comments/1hyh4g/borderlands_2_bunkers_badasses_shift_loot_yall/cazioi4?context=7) and these Gearbox forums posts: [(1)](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=4348304&postcount=299), [(2)](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=4348556&postcount=302), it will spawn a random  TTAODK class mod (random prefix, rarity, skill bonuses, etc) at your level. I've edited my answer to include this info.